# Установка и использование SDK в разные версии Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x, python-3.6, python-2.7

Установлено две версии python 2.7 и 3.6. Есть SDK которая установлена только в python 2.7. В связи с тем, что 2.7 поддержка закончилась, возникает необходимость установить этот же SDK и в python 3, при этом поддержка SDK в python 2.7 должна остаться. То есть на компе **должны быть два питона разных версий в каждом из которых одинаковый SDK**.

Исходные данные:

ОС - windows 10. Установка SDK на python 2.7 проводилась батником. Содержимое bat:

```
pip install --upgrade -f wheelhouse -r file_list.txt
```

**file_list.txt** вот такого содержания (строк больше, просто для примера):

```
wheelhouse/dn_tools-0.0.1-py2-none-any.whl
```

Стуктура в папке SDK:

```
/wheelhouse
/wheelhouse_linux
LICENSE
README
install.bat
install.sh
file_list.txt
linux_file_list.txt
```

В wheelhouse лежат файлы с расширением whl. Путем переименовывания их в zip доступно содержимое.

Comment: похоже что нужно подредактировать bat:   pip3 install --upgrade -f wheelhouse -r file_list.txt

Comment: а в чем заключается вопрос/проблема?

Comment: проблема исчерпана

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Под Windows можно использовать утилиту py, которая позволяет выбирать, какой именно интерпретатор Python нужно использовать для указанной далее команды.

То есть для Python 2.7 можно выполнить команду:

```
py -2.7 -m pip install --upgrade -f wheelhouse -r file_list.txt
```

А для Python 3.6:

```
py -3.6 -m pip install --upgrade -f wheelhouse -r file_list.txt
```