# Команда python -m venv venv выводит слово "Python"

Tags: python, venv

Мне нужно создать виртуальное окружение для проекта на Python. В папке прописываю команду

```
python -m venv venv
```

Выводит следующее:

```
Python
```

Скриншот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: весьма частый вопрос. знатоки, надеюсь, помогут найти дубликаты.

Comment: Вот что-то похожее: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1423685

Comment: видимо, что-то вроде [этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1136774/178576) или [этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1391363/178576) или [этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1070533/178576)

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо @wchistow. Помогла [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1423685/%d0%9e%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b5), где предлагается установить интерпретатор python.

Похоже терминал не видел python, хотя я установил его с официального сайта.

[image: теперь powershell не вывел "Python" папка "venv" создалась)]